# Identifying various parts on a DC motor from a hybrid vehicle ABS pump

Tags: motor, dc, identification, wiring

I have a DC motor that I pulled off of an ABS pump from a hybrid vehicle.

I need to get this ABS to work because a new motor is way too costly. I think I could salvage it. I just need to solder and grind a new brush down properly. My issue is, there are a few parts on this motor that I don't understand their purpose.

1. Why does this motor have 3 carbon brushes? I thought they generally have two.
2. What is the purpose of the large copper spring?
3. Why are there two mini capacitor looking things wired into the the base plate?

Comment: your question belongs at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `I'm not sure if that lead was connected to that spring end or the base plate.` ... aways take lots of pictures before, and during disassembly

Comment: the bottom picture shows what looks like a fried wire

Comment: I don't have the before pictures. That's why I wasn't sure if it was connected or not.

Answer (score 2):

3 brushes is one way of doing two speeds.

Same with 4 brushes or could even be reverse.

Comment: Do you know what the two capacitor looking things are?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of the large copper spring?
> Why are there two mini capacitor looking things wired into the the base plate?

That's the filter to reduce the unwanted emissions from the motor arcing.

Comment: Yes this one has 3 brushes. I also have another motor from an ABS unit that has 4 brushes. What does the two little capacitor thingies do?

Comment: Do you know how the this DC motor would be wired? Im pretty noob when it comes to electronics. 

Would it be all wired in series? Is it correct to say that electricity would go into one prone, through the inductance spring, through the capacitors, through the brush, through the commutator and back out to the other lead?

Comment: "Do you know ..." If I had known I would have answered. You asked two separate questions. I answered one of them. You really should not ask two questions in one post. You should create two separate posts one for each question.